# Build Combobox with Item Selected

Tags: php, html, combobox

Trying to create a combo box with the user's current value selected. I'm thinking my issue is with the apostrophe's and quotes - can anyone with a sharp eye help? Variable $MCI is created before any quotes/apostrophes and is functioning properly.

```
$MCI = '';
$MCI = $row['MobileCarrierID'];

echo '
<select name="MobileCarrierName">
<?php 
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT MobileCarrierID, MobileCarrierName FROM tblMobileCarrier ORDER BY MobileCarrierName;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$MCISelected = (' . $MCI . '==$row["MobileCarrierID"] ? " selected" : "");
echo "<option value=" . $row['MobileCarrierID'] . $MCISelected . ">" . $row['MobileCarrierName'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
echo '
<select name="MobileCarrierName">
<?php 
$sql=
```

which needs to be changed to

```
echo '<select name="MobileCarrierName">';
$sql=
```

Also

```
$MCISelected = (' . $MCI . '==$row["MobileCarrierID"] ? " selected" : "");
```

needs to be changed to

```
$MCISelected = ($MCI==$row["MobileCarrierID"])? " selected" : "";
```

And your mysqli_query is missing the database connection ie

```
mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

Finally, close off with

```
echo '</select>';
```

Your quotes and brackets are off and you've placed your selected variable inside your value in the option, a complete edited code should look something like...

```
<?php
echo '<select name="MobileCarrierName">';
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MobileCarrierID, MobileCarrierName FROM tblMobileCarrier ORDER BY MobileCarrierName;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$MCISelected = ($MCI==$row["MobileCarrierID"])? " selected" : "";
echo '<option '.$MCIselected.' value="'.$row["MobileCarrierID"].'">'.$row["MobileCarrierName"].'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

Check out [How to set an option from multiple options or array with different values to views as selected in select box using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070359/how-to-set-an-option-from-multiple-options-or-array-with-different-values-to-vie) for a guide on how it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT MobileCarrierID, MobileCarrierName FROM tblMobileCarrier ORDER BY MobileCarrierName;");
?>
<select name="MobileCarrierName">
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $MCI = $row['MobileCarrierID'];
    $MCISelected = ($MCI==$row["MobileCarrierID"]) ? " selected" : "";
    echo "<option value=".$MCI." ".$MCISelected.">".$row['MobileCarrierName']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

try this one