# Selected in option from while PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, selected

I have a problem to select the preferred value

```js
<?php
...
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   $selected_rep = ($row['ID']=67) ? 'selected="selected"' :'';
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<option $selected_rep value='". $row["ID"]."'>" . $row["NUME"]. ' '. $row["PRENUME"]. "</option>\n";
   }
}
...
?>
```

I want to select the value with ID=67.
Not function `$selected_rep` ,select all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the selected test inside the loop where it has access to the loaded `$row` for each of the resultset rows you are processing

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $selected_rep = ($row['ID'] == 67) ? 'selected="selected"' :'';

        echo "<option $selected_rep value='". $row["ID"]."'>" . $row["NUME"]. ' '. $row["PRENUME"]. "</option>\n";
   }
}
```

Ahhh and you write test using `==` and not `=`

`==` is this equal to that

`=` set this to that

Comment: To expand on this, you were setting the value outside the loop so it never changed. Inside it can work as you want

Comment: not work, the result is the same in view-source is: `<option selected="selected" value='67'>Name 1 </option>
<option selected="selected" value='67'>Name 2</option>
<option selected="selected" value='67'>Name 3</option>
<option selected="selected" value='67'>Name 4</option>`

Comment: See amended `$row['ID'] == 67` instead of `$row['ID'] = 67`

Comment: 'selected="selected"' isn't required, 'selected' will do the job. It's a duplicate of a Q/A I posted a couple of days back... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070359/how-to-set-an-option-from-multiple-options-or-array-with-different-values-to-vie and an answer from yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071127/build-combobox-with-item-selected 2 votes up in under 10 minutes and not marked as a duplicate by an admin pushes proof to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928553/php-allow-user-to-comment-and-rate-only-once-with-their-ip-adress

Comment: It works as just `selected` but the html spec I believe says `selected` is a boolean and therefore should be set to something truthy

Comment: You can input selected='yelp', selected='itdoesntreallymatter' or selected='prettymuchwhatyoulike' or simply 'selected' and it will still come out as selected. I've ran it in every browser and it always works. There MAY have been a time when it wasn't true, but it certainly isn't the case anymore. Again, it's still pretty much an exact duplicate of an answer posted yesterday